# Error in openccart when i click on order

Tags: php, opencart2.x

When i click on order page in admin its show following error how can i resolve it

Not Found

```
Not Found

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /giftandshop/index.php was not found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Above comment not clearing, please check the error log files from the server end mention the error.

Comment: in admin panel when i click on Sale > Order this error come as a alert.